# Didn't get dijit.Tree to lazy loading

Tags: grails, lazy-loading, dijit.tree

I need to lazy-load the directories into a `dijit.Tree` which is in a `dijit.form.Dialog`.
I get the root directories and I can put them into the tree with the root node 'Computer',
but I can't figure out how to get the lazy-loading to work.

When I click on a node, I call a function which makes an ajax call to get the children of the selected node. I can fetch them and render them as JSON back to the gsp (I think they are well formed). But when I try to put them into the store, it fails. I can't get `store.newItem()` to work. I don't really know if it's the right and easiest way to do this anyway. I searched and tried and failed and unfortunately, I'm stuck.

I use:

- Grails 1.3.9
- Dojo Toolkit 1.6

The way how I get the dataStore to the gsp:

```
    File [] roots = File.listRoots()        
    def item = []

    roots.each{
        item << [
            name         : it.getAbsolutePath(),
            path         : it.getAbsolutePath(),
            children     : []
        ]
    }
    def store = [
        identifier: 'path',
        label: 'name',
        items: item
    ]

    def retVal = [store: store]

    render retVal as JSON
```

Definition of store, model and tree:

```
    function prepare(dataStore) {                           
        var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({
               data: dataStore
        });
        var treeModel = new dijit.tree.ForestStoreModel({
               store: store,
               rootId : "root",
               rootLabel : "Computer",
               childrenAttrs: ["children"]
       });
       var treeControl = new dijit.Tree({
               id: 'directoryTree',
               model: treeModel,
               autoExpand: false,
               onClick: loadDirectories
               },
               "treeOne");
       }
```

Here the code how I try to edit the store, data is a list:

```
    data = [
        [name: 'info', path: 'C:\temp\info', children: []]
        [name: 'grmpf', path: 'C:\temp\grmpf', children: []]
        ...
    ]

    for(i=0; i < data.length; i++){
      store.newItem({name: data[i].name, path: data[i].path, children: data[i].children}, {parent: parent.path[0], attribute: 'children'}); 
      store.save(); 
    }
```

I tried it this way and once, I deleted the item, edited the item and put it into the store again. But nothing worked..

If anyone can give me any insights, I would appreciate it!

Comment: Please show some critical code.

Comment: I edited my entry and put some code in it. If you need more, please ask

Comment: any errors in firebug console?

Comment: @h4b0 : Yeah, "dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore: Invalid item argument", but I don't know what of the item is invalid

Comment: add some `console.log` outputs before `store.newItem()`: `console.log(data)`, `console.log(data[i])`, `console.log(data[i].name)`, `console.log(data[i].path)` and `console.log(data[i].children`. what is `parent.path[0]`?

Comment: @h4b0: I have some console.log outputs there and everything seems fine. Every data had a name, a unique path and 'nothing' for children. Children should be an empty list. parent is the node where I need to put the data into. And parent.path[0] is the unique path, so that the store knows where to put the data

Comment: problem seems to be with your `ItemFileReadStore`. add your store definition to your question.

Comment: do you use `dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore` anywhere in your code? please post `loadDirectores()` (if it's not too long) and your json data. could you set it all up on jsfiddle?

Comment: @h4b0 No, I don't use it. I used it, but then I got the Error that 'store.newItem()' is not a function. So I changed it to ItemFileWriteStore. I will need some time to set it up on jsfiddle. I never used it..

Comment: @h4b0 I don't know if I used jsfiddle the right way... :-/  http://jsfiddle.net/mWuPS/

Comment: I fixed your jsfiddle, but I'm unable to solve your problem : / http://jsfiddle.net/mWuPS/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, I found the very strange problem...

Well, I tried :

```
    store.newItem(jsObj, parent);
    store.save();
```

The solution:

```
    model.newItem(jsObj, parent);
```

Instead of adding the item to store, I put it into the model and then it works.
I really do not know why. Maybe someone can explain it to me.
Thanks